# Find duplicates of two columns from csv

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

I want to find duplicate values of one column and replaced with value of another column of csv which has multiple columns. So first I put two columns from the csv to the dictionary. Then I want to find duplicate values of dictionary that has string values and keys. I tried with solutions of remove duplicates of dictionary but got the error as not hashable or no result. Here is the first part of code.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools as it

mydict = {}
index = 0
reader = csv.reader(open(r"computing.csv", "rb"))
for i, rows in enumerate(reader):
    if i == 0: 
    continue

    if len(rows) == 0:
        continue
    k = rows[3].strip()      
    v = rows[2].strip()    
    if k in mydict:        
        mydict[k].append(v)
    else:
        mydict[k] = [v]

#mydict = hash(frozenset(mydict))

print mydict

d = {}
while True:
    try:        
        d = defaultdict(list)
        for k,v in mydict.iteritems():
            #d[frozenset(mydict.items())]
            d[v].append(k)
    except:
        continue

writer = csv.writer(open(r"OLD.csv", 'wb'))
for key, value in d.items():
    writer.writerow([key, value])
```

Comment: When I'm running the code I'm getting "TypeError: unhasable type: list." Is this the error you've been getting?

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand.  You say that you want to "find duplicate values of one column and replaced with value of another column of csv".   The way this sentence is structured makes the reader think that you want to replace a duplicate value in one column with an entire column.  It makes no sense.  Can you clarify this?

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins I got the error "TypeError: unhasable type: list." too. Please look at my other comment. The input is two columns from input csv and the output is one column in the final csv. For the repetitive case, my idea is to use dictionary. How can I get the desired result using dictionary?

Comment: @ nater Sorry, I don't want to replace a duplicate value in one column with an entire column. The csv has rows and columns. If C580 is the same as C980, I want to replace them with E580 and E980, with the respective rows. If not, use only column 'C' cell values. But the final output is to use only one column of unique values of column 'C'. Does this make sense?

Comment: Please update the question with a sample of your input and your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear. So I hope I got it right.

Please give an example of input columns and the desired output columns.
Please give a printout of the error and let us know which line caused the error.

if `column1=[1,2,3,1,4]` and `column2=[a,b,c,d,e]` do you want the output to be `n_column1=[a,2,3,d,4]` and `column2  =[1,b,c,d,e]`

I imagine the exception was in `d[v].append(k)` since clearly v is a list. you cannot use a list as a key in a dictionary.

```
In [1]: x = [1,2,3,1,4]

In [2]: y = ['a','b','c','d','e']

In [5]: from collections import defaultdict

In [6]: d = defaultdict(int)

In [7]: for a in x:
   ...:     d[a] += 1


In [8]: d
Out[8]: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1})

In [9]: x2 = []

In [10]: for a,b in zip(x,y):
   ....:     x2.append(a if d[a]==1 else b)
   ....:     

In [11]: x
Out[11]: [1, 2, 3, 1, 4]

In [12]: x2
Out[12]: ['a', 2, 3, 'd', 4]
```

In that case, I guess if I had to change your code to fit. I'd do something like that:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools as it

mydict = {}
index = 0
reader = csv.reader(open(r"computing.csv", "rb"))
histogram = defaultdict(int)
k = []
v = []
for i, rows in enumerate(reader):
    if i == 0: 
        continue

    if len(rows) == 0:
        continue
    k.append(rows[3].strip())
    v.append(rows[2].strip())

    item = k[-1]
    histogram[item] += 1

output_column = []

for first_item, second_item in zip(k,v):
    output_column.append(first_item if histogram[first_item]==1 else second_item)

writer = csv.writer(open(r"OLD.csv", 'wb'))
for c1, c2 in zip(output_column, v):
    writer.writerow([c1, c2])
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the question with example. The example is true to first part. The input rows of column 'C' in csv are like [a1,b1,c1,a1,e1,...] and column 'E' are like [m6,g2,t4,d1,u3,...]. Literally these two columns are unique keys in the input csv. My goal is the output column in the final csv is to use one column from two columns of input csv  e.g. column 'B', like [m6,b1,c1,d1,e1,...] .But if I use only the column 'C' value, some are repetitive.

Comment: So my idea is to use column 'E' in the repeated place. I want to extract these two columns from csv and put them into the dictionary of key and value so that I can find the repeated values of dictionary and if repeated, the respected values are replaced with the unique keys of dictionary. If not repeated, the values are used. Finally, I want to write csv with dictionary into one column along with other columns of input csv.

Comment: Well, my example did what you wanted. I edited the answer to reflect your code, altered so it should work.

Comment: why is defaultdict(int) used? Both columns are strings.

Comment: Because the histogram dict is a counter of frequency.  To detect what items repeat more than once...

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Your code doesn't produce the output. It just takes each character from the key to the histogram and the output column only produces separate letters. The keys and values of dictionary are strings like row 2 of csv - 'TIUI349', 'PL-498'

Comment: Ok, I fixed it, I think. Can't test this because I dont have your input files, but it should be ok now - or you should be able to make it work.